# What's the least number of combinations you need to determine who the most efficient members are?

Tags: combinatorics

Not sure if this question fits here, but it's something I was thinking about last night.  Maybe someone can throw some light on it.

Let's say I have a group of people doing some shared task.  Let's say they're picking apples.  And let's say I have to choose 3 people from a pool of six people to do the work each day.  There are 20 combinations of people I can choose from.  I could try all those combinations, and then choose the combination that picked the most apples.

But let's say you can choose any number of those combinations before you decide on your 3-person team.  What's the least number of combinations you need to try before you can calculate who the 3 most efficient members are?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume the following:

- You are able to keep a log of productivity and don't forget information once it is learned
- You are only able to test groups of three for productivity, not individuals
- Individual productivity of each applepicker remains constant each day regardless of who they are partnered with.  (e.g. If Steve contributed by picking 7 apples monday, he will again contribute 7 apples on tuesday if picked for the team)

Reworded, we have a [totally ordered multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) of $k$ elements, we'll call it $X=\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k\}$, and the family $\mathcal{F}=\{F\subset X~:~|F|=3\}$ which also has an induced total order: $F \leq F' \Leftrightarrow x_i+x_j+x_k\leq x_i'+x_j'+x_k'$ where $F=\{x_i,x_j,x_k\}\in\mathcal{F}$ and $F'=\{x_i',x_j',x_k'\}\in\mathcal{F}$.  We are tasked then with finding a supremum of $\mathcal{F}$.

> You can determine the order of $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ in four days

Begin by recording the results for the four combinations of picking three elements of $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$.  The element which is missing from the team with the least productivity must have been the largest element out of the first four.  The element missing from the team with the second smallest productivity must have been the second largest out of the first four.  Finally, the third largest element must be the remaining element in the best team.

- From here on out, refer to the **current largest** as $c_1$, the **current second largest** as $c_2$, and the **current third largest** as $c_3$.

$\color{red}{\star\star}$ Continue inductively until exhausting all elements by taking the next untested element, $x_i$, and finding the total: $c_1+c_2+x_i$.  Compare the result to the already known result $c_1+c_2+c_3$.

**If** $c_1+c_2+x_i\leq c_1+c_2+c_3$ then $x_i\leq c_3$ and discard $x_i$ and continue at $\color{red}{\star\star}$ with $x_{i+1}$.

**Else** we learn then that $x_i>c_3$.  We want to learn if $x_i\leq c_2$ or $x_i>c_2$.  To do so, find the total $c_1+x_i+c_3$ and compare the result to the already known result $c_1+c_2+c_3$.

..**If** $c_1+x_i+c_3\leq c_1+c_2+c_3$ then we learn that $c_3<x_i\leq c_2$ so set $x_i$ as the new current third largest, $c_3$, and continue from $\color{red}{\star\star}$ by starting to determine the ranking of $x_{i+1}$

..**Else** we learn then that $x_i>c_2$.  We want to learn if $x_i\leq c_1$ or $x_i>c_1$.  To do so, find the total $x_i+c_2+c_3$ and compare the result to the already known result $c_1+c_2+c_3$.

....**If** $x_i+c_2+c_3\leq c_1+c_2+c_3$ then we learn that $c_2<x_i\leq c_1$ so set $c_2$ as the new current third largest, $c_3$, and set $x_i$ as the new current second largest, $c_2$, and continue from $\color{red}{\star\star}$ by starting to determine the ranking of $x_{i+1}$.

....**Else** we learn that $x_i>c_1$.  Set $c_2$ as the new current third largest, set $c_1$ as the new current second largest, and set $x_i$ as the new current largest.  Continue from $\color{red}{\star\star}$ by starting to determine the ranking of $x_{i+1}$.

---

The worst runtime for this algorithm will occur when $x_1<x_2<x_3<\dots<x_k$ in which case it requires a total of four measurements to order the first four elements, and then a total of three measurements for each of the remaining $k-4$ elements to fit them into the top3 rankings, for a total runtime of $4+3(k-4) = 3k-8$ steps

The best runtime for this algorithm will occur when $x_1>x_2>x_3>\dots>x_k$ in which case it requires a total of four measurements to order the first four elements, and then a total of one measurement for each of the remaining $k-4$ elements, for a total runtime of $4+(k-4)=k$ steps.

For your specific example of having six people, it will take me somewhere between 6 and 10 days (inclusive) to pick the best team of three.